# Prove that $1+\tan^2 x=\sec^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

I have no idea how to prove this. Does anyone know where to start? We're allowed to use other trigonometric identities but i'm not sure why these are useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: start off with the identity $$\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x) \equiv 1$$ and divide through by $\cos^2(x)$ and your result should follow immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : I hope you know that $\tan x=\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$. Then use $\sin^2x+\cos^2 x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the definitions in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.
$$
\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \\
\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x}
$$